# Why is systrace insecure?

Tags: openbsd

Why is the:

http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=systrace&sektion=4

Systrace marked as insecure?

Can someone explain the "why"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was based on a paper presented at the USENIX conference entitled *"“Exploiting Concurrency Vulnerabilities in System Call Wrappers"*

According to the author in a [blog post](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2007/08/06/usenix-woot07-exploiting-concurrency-vulnerabilities-in-system-call-wrappers-and-the-evil-genius/):

*The key insight here is that the historic assumption of “atomicity” of system calls is falacious, and that on both uniprocessor and multiprocessing systems, it is trivial to construct a race between system call wrappers and malicious user processes to bypass protections. I demonstrated sample exploit code against the Sysjail policy on Systrace, and IDwrappers on GSWTK, but the paper includes a more extensive discussion including vulnerabilities in sudo’s Systrace monitor mode."*

Even though it may be trivial to bypass the system call wrapping, I'm not sure whether other protections (for example on directories, files, URLs, etc.) that are wrapped are also affected.   I'm also not sure how much damage these malicious processes can do if they are forced to have race conditions with the system calls.  Maybe someone who understands this better can clarify it.

Comment: USENIX WOOT07, Exploiting Concurrency Vulnerabilities in System Call Wrappers, and the Evil Genius

Comment: August 6th, 2007 at 20:33 UTC by Robert N. M. Watson

Answer (score 3):

I did not find anything on that page that describes [Systrace](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/systrace/) as insecure.

Systrace was the result of groundbreaking research, described here:

- [Improving Host Security with System Call Policies](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/papers/systrace.pdf), Niels Provos, USENIX Security 2003.

Later research reported vulnerabilities in system call monitoring tools (including Systrace):

- [Exploiting Concurrency Vulnerabilities in System Call Wrappers](http://www.watson.org/~robert/2007woot/2007usenixwoot-exploitingconcurrency.pdf), Robert Watson, WOOT 2007.  [blog post](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2007/08/06/usenix-woot07-exploiting-concurrency-vulnerabilities-in-system-call-wrappers-and-the-evil-genius/).

I do not know the status of those vulnerabilities.  I don't know whether Systrace has been patched to defend against those attacks.